# Date gets converted to utc automatically upon sending to frontend

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm receiving a date from a `node.js` backend in flutter. The date is converted to the users timezone in node.js.
For some reason, flutter automatically converts it to utc. How can I receive the dateTime as is and not have flutter convert it?

> **Background**: The way it works is flutter first sends a dateTime to the
> backend already converted to utc so that it can be stored in the db in
> utc. then anytime the backend sends back a date, it converts it to the
> timezone the user was in when signing up. (not sure if this is a good
> way of doing time conversion...)

**UPDATE:**

Seems like `DateTime.parse` always converts to utc... Any way to stop that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using DateTime.parse, it says in the documentation that the way to handle the changing of time-zone is by providing an optional time-zone offset part in your date.

```
DateTime.parse("2020-09-21T14:00:00") // 2020-09-21 14:00:00.000
DateTime.parse("2020-09-21T14:00:00-1230") // 2020-09-22 02:30:00.000Z
```

Check out the documentation here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your code on how you're doing it. Thanks.